# Not found when using ajax in dynamic dropdown in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my php code, I have two dropdowns which is the other one depends on the first one.

Here is the first dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control style" id="sel" >
    <option style="color: black;" >Select...</option>
    <?php foreach ($dtype as $row ) { ?>
    <option style"color:black;" value="<?php echo $row['donations_type_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row['donations_type_name'];?></option>
    <?php }?>                               
</select>  
<tr>
<td>Available Donation:</td>
<td style="color: black; ">
    <select name='avail' id='avail' class="form-control style" >
        <option style="color:black;" value="">Select...</option>                    
    </select>   
</td>
</tr>
```

The second dropdown shows the data that corresponds whatever the user selects from the first dropdown.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sel").change(function(){  
    $.ajax({         
    data: {id: $(this).val()},  
    type: "POST",  
     url:"<?= base_url() ?>BeneficiaryModule/showAvailable/"+ $(this).val(),  
    success:function(data){  
    $("#avail").html(data);  
    }       
   });  
});
});
</script>
```

In my controller:

```
public function showAvailable()
    {
    echo $id = $this->input->post('id', true);
    $data['package'] = $this->Beneficiary_model->getDtype($id);
    $output = null;
    foreach ($data['package'] as $row ) {
        $output.="<option value='".$row->package_id."'>".$row->package_name."</option>";
    }
    echo $output;        
}
```

And in my model:

```
public function getDtype($id){
    $this->db->select('package_id','package_name');
    $this->db->from('package_table');
    $this->db->where('package_type', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

When I tried to run the code and debug it through F12, it shows there that `POST http://localhost:8999/samp/sampModule/showAvailable/2 404 (Not Found)`

Why is it?

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: try changing `base_url()` to `site_url()`

Comment: It works! but I have to find out why the choices in the second dropdown doesn't show anything.

Comment: that means your query is returning null data set

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sel").change(function(){  
    $.ajax({         
        data: {id: $(this).val()}, 
...
        url:"<?= base_url() ?>BeneficiaryModule/showAvailable/"+ $(this).val(),
```

Take `$(this)` out of `ajax` object. It points now to ajax object itself. Try:

```
$("#sel").change(function(){  
    var _id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({         
        data: {id: _id},
...
        url:"<?= base_url() ?>BeneficiaryModule/showAvailable/"+ _id,      

**UPDATED**
```

Also, if the data is received from the server correctly but dropdown is still not rendered, the issue might be with the `dataType` property. There may be some problems with the response mime type, that cause the problem with the `Intelligent Guess` and data is treated as a `json` or `xml` string, so you can try to set it explicit:

```
$("#sel").change(function(){  
    var _id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({         
        data: {id: _id},  
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: 'html',
        url:"<?= base_url() ?>BeneficiaryModule/showAvailable/"+ _id,  
        success:function(data){  
            $("#avail").html(data);  
        }       
    });

 });
```

Comment: What was the url of the request in "F12/ network tab"? And what is the url of the page where the request is handled.

Comment: I just changed the base_url to site_url. Now the error is resolved but the second dropdown doesn't show anything. I still have to find out.

Comment: So, what does request return? Is id passed correctly?

Comment: Yes the ID passed  correctly. It says, `Undefined property: stdClass::$package_name`

Comment: @gvIC try to add a 'die()' after 'echo $output'

Comment: Through the F12, I was able to view now the results and it worked fine but it doesn't show on the second dropdown? What am I missing?

Comment: Well, assuming on your assertion that the data is correctly received from the server, it seems that javascript doesn't render the dropwdown. Try to specify explicit `dataType: 'html'` in ajax parameters. Maybe there are some issues with the response mime type, that cause the problem with the `Intelligent Guess` and data is treated as a `json` or `xml` string.  I'll update my answer.